# How to create a ProgressBar equal to this

Tags: android, progress-bar

I need your help, I need to create a ProgressBar equal to this, I searched in many places but I found nothing like the most I could do, was leave it all in one color only, but need to divide in 5 colors as in the image, can help me ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCJwU.png

Comment: Maybe this sounds pretty lame, but you could take the one you already did in one color, and then use CSS gradient to make different colors from 0-19%(color1), 19-20%(white), 20-39%(color2), 39-40%(white)...
Just an idea

Answer (score 0):

Some application use images to show it's like a progress bar as I far my suggestion you should take  5 image(different progress stage) and show them one by one according to progress 
As in the image I think now it indicating it is in froth stage out of five you should take five different stage showing image and change the image in progress